# Joining 2 tables in SQL using a common third

Tags: sql, join, oracle11g, inner-join

I have three tables and i'm trying to return details from 2 of them, however they do not have a direct link, so i have to use a common 3rd table to join them.  I'm using SQL developer - Oracle 11g

Here is a very simple view of the tables:

```
  Country

  CID | CName
  -------------
  ENG | England
  FRA | France


  Branch

  BID | Branch Name | RegionID | CID
  ------------------------------
  B1  | ABC         | R1       | ENG
  B2  | DEF         | R1       | ENG
  B3  | GHI         | R2       | FRA

  Region

  RegionID| RegionName
  ------------------------------
  R1      | UK    
  R2      | CEurope
```

This is just a very basic sample to illustrate.  I want the query to return:

```
  RegionID| RegionName | CID  | CName
  ------------------------------
  R1      | UK         | ENG  | England    
  R2      | CEurope    | FRA  | France
```

So i want to return data from the Region Table and Country using branch as a common link.

Here is my current code which doesn't seem to be working:

```
Select
  c.CID, 
  c.CName, 
  r.RegionID, 
  r.RegionName
FROM
  Regions r inner join 
  (
  Branch b inner join Countries c on c.CID = b.BID 
  )
  on b.RegionID = r.RegionID;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT
  c.CID, 
  c.CName, 
  r.RegionID, 
  r.RegionName
FROM
  Regions r 
  INNER JOIN Branch b ON b.RegionID = r.RegionID
  INNER JOIN Countries c ON c.CID = b.CID;
```

Comment: Thanks this did the trick, not sure why i was over complicating it, makes much more sense now.  Also thanks to Hawk who had the same answer!

Answer (score 2):

This is not how we do join in SQL. You may consider having a look at this simple [reference](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/joins.php). For your script, whether you need to use mid-table or not; you need to specify which column you are going to link using `ON` phrase. the following could work:

```
SELECT c.cid, 
       c.cname, 
       r.regionid, 
       r.regionname 
FROM   regions r 
       INNER JOIN branch b 
               ON b.regionid = r.regionid 
       INNER JOIN countries c 
               ON c.cid = b.cid;
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably need a b.CID in the join on Countries